# looking to combine all list of objects into single string

Tags: c#, .net

I have below class

```
public class ComponentRedundancy
{
    public int EquipmentQuantity { get; set; }
    public double RedundancyPercentage { get; set; }
    public Redundancy Redundancy { get; set; }
}
```

and below is an enum

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
public enum Redundancy
{
    [Description("N")]
    N,
    [Description("N+1")]
    N_PLUS_1,
    [Description("2N")]
    N_MULTIPLY_2
}
```

and i am having these objects

```
  List<ComponentRedundancy> componentRedundancy = new List<ComponentRedundancy>();
  componentRedundancy.Add(new ComponentRedundancy(1, 70, N_MULTIPLY_2));
  componentRedundancy.Add(new ComponentRedundancy(2, 50, N_PLUS_1));
  componentRedundancy.Add(new ComponentRedundancy(3, 40, N));
```

I am looking combine all these values and the result would like this in single line string

```
 [1@70%](2N)[2@50%](N+1)[3@40%](N)
```

Could any one please let me know any idea or suggestions on how can i get the required format like above from the list, many thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry my bad i updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle the conversion of the `enum` to a custom string, we could write a method:

```
private static string Convert(Redundancy r)
{
    switch (r)
    {
        case Redundancy.N:
            return "N";
        case Redundancy.N_MULTIPLY_2:
            return "2N";
        case Redundancy.N_PLUS_1:
            return "N+1";
        default:
            return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

And then we can use `string.Concat` to join all the strings into one, using `Select` to select the custom string for each item:

```
string results = string.Concat(componentRedundancy.Select(cr =>
    $"[{cr.EquipmentQuantity}@{cr.RedundancyPercentage}%]({Convert(cr.Redundancy)})"));
```